# Delete whitespace characters up to previous non-whitespace character

Tags: vim, macvim

In Vim, say I have the following:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a href="#">link</a>
```

If my cursor is on the `<` of the `<a>` tag, how can I delete the preceding whitespace characters up to (but not including) the `>` of the `<p>`?

`d` `b` almost does it, but it also deletes the closing `>` in the `<p>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this exact scenario I would just join lines with `-Jx` or `kJx`.

- `k` or `-` to go up one line
- `J` to join the current line with the following line.
- `x` to remove the remaining space character.